# Adding a code snippets to web page without php

Tags: html, web, frontend

Im have a code, and i want this to my page, ofcourse I can programming a new div for this with everythink, but maybe here is a easy way to do this?

```
 <h2>HTML/CSS</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="introduction"></i>Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="structure"></i>Structure</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use :

```
<xmp>
<h2>HTML/CSS</h2>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="home"></i>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="introduction"></i>Introduction</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="structure"></i>Structure</a></li>
</ul>
</xmp>
```